# $K_0((k[x]/(x^2))[y])$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-k-theory, picard-group

Let $K_0(R):= K_0(P(R))$ where $P(R)$ is the category of finitely generated projective $R$-modules, where $R$ is a commutative ring with unity. Now if $R = k[x]/(x^2)$, $R$ is a local ring thus all finitely generated projective $R$ modules are free, hence $K_0(R) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. But what about $K_0((k[x]/(x^2))[y])$? Since it is Noetherian of dimension $1$, I can understand that it will be isomorphic to $[Spec(R[y]),\mathbb{Z}] \oplus Pic(R[y])$, where $[Spec(R[y]),\mathbb{Z}]$ is the ring of all continuous maps from $Spec(R[y])$ to $\mathbb{Z}$. Now $Spec(R[y])$ will have finitely many components say $s$ since $R$ is noetherian. Thus $K_0(R[y]) \cong \mathbb{Z}^s \oplus Pic(R[y])$. After this, I am unable to proceed if you could help me I would be grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $P$ be a finitely generated projective module over your ring $S=R[y]=k[x,y]/y^2$.  Then $P/yP$ is a finitely generated projective module over $k[x]$, and so is free by the Quillen-Suslin theorem.  By choosing a basis and lifting it to $P$, we obtain a map $\alpha\colon R^n\to P$ such that the induced map $(R/y)^n\to P/yP$ is an isomorphism.  Thus for $v\in P$ we can choose $u\in R^n$ and $v'\in P$ with $\alpha(u)=v+yv'$, then we can choose $u'$ and $v''$ with $\alpha(u')=v'+yv''$, which gives $\alpha(u-yu')=v$.  This shows that $\alpha$ is surjective.

We can express $P$ as a retract of a free $S$-module $F$, and it is easy to see that  $yF=\text{ann}(y,F)$, so it follows that $\text{ann}(y,P)=yP=\alpha(y.R^n)$.  Now suppose we have $u\in R^n$ with $\alpha(u)=0$.  As $\alpha$ is an isomorphism mod $y$ we must have $u=yu'$ for some $u'$.  Now $y.\alpha(u')=\alpha(u)=0$, so $\alpha(u')\in\text{ann}(y,P)=\alpha(y.R^n)$ so $\alpha(u')=\alpha(yu'')$ for some $u''$.  Now $\alpha(u'-yu'')=0$ so we can run the same argument again to get $u'-yu''=yu'''$ for some $u'''$.  We can now multiply by $y$ to get $u=0$.  Thus $\alpha$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Oh, great, how did I miss the fact that $(k[x]/(x^2))[y] \cong k[x,y]/(x^2)$. Thanks a lot for your detailed proof. So basically in brief $(x)$ is a nilpotent ideal of $R[y]$ and $K_0(R[y]/I) \cong K_0(R[y])$ thus $K_0(R[y]) = K_0(k[y]) = \mathbb{Z}$. Right?